# Double encryption vs single encryption

Tags: cryptography

So I understand that double encryption would do no more than possibly double the time taken to break a single encryption, as the key size of double encryption would be 2k-bits and the size of single would be k-bits. But in terms of strength, is double encryption stronger than single encryption and is there a specific way to express how much stronger it is than single encryption? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by double encryption? Same or different algorithms? Same or different keys?

Comment: I suppose it would be two different keys as the keys are chosen uniformly at random. The algorithms would be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I understand that double encryption would do no more than possibly double > the time taken to break a single encryption, as the key size of double
> encryption would be 2k-bits and the size of single would be k-bits.

Not exactly. While it is true that you *need* 2k bits for double encryption (you have two keys, each k bits in size), the strength of the encryption would be equivalent to k+1 bits.

That's because as you correctly deduced, the brute force time is going to be doubled; and *that* is equivalent to adding a single bit to the key. When bruteforcing, you would run 2<sup>k</sup> with the k+1-*th* bit at 0, and 2<sup>k</sup> attempts with the k+1-*th* bit at 1; this extra bit sort of represents whether you're bruteforcing the outer or the inner encryption.

## Update (clarification)

The key factor here is the encryption architecture. More precisely, whether you have a way of *telling whether the outer encryption has been successful or not*.

For example, if we encrypt a ZIP file twice, and supply a bad password to the outer ZIP, this will either give us an error, or something which is not a ZIP file. **So we don't need - or just *can't* - bruteforce the result, because we know it isn't going to end well**.

When the decrypted ZIP file yields a valid encrypted ZIP file, then we know the bruteforce succeeded and *now* can start bruteforcing the new ZIP file thus obtained.

In this scenario, the above holds: the total run time is that of the outer bruteforce, plus that of the inner bruteforce.

The answer has been accepted, so I guess that's the scenario the OP had in mind too. But it's not the only possible scenario.

Suppose we run a low-level library AES encrypt of a string, giving just a block of apparently random bits with nothing even to say it's an AES encryption at all, and then we encrypt *that* block with AES again, yielding a different "outer" block of apparently random bits: no header, no signature, no checksum.

Now, testing any key with AES against the outer block will yield a block of random bits, **but we don't know whether the decryption succeeded or not**. We don't know this is the *right* block of random bits. To know this, we need to bruteforce the block, and see if the output block is a non-random, valid cleartext or not.

(The OTP code is "perfect" in that regard, since even after obtaining a plausible cleartext, you still can't know whether it is the *correct* cleartext: "ATTACK AT NIGHT" and "RETREAT AT ONCE" are both equally likely outcomes of a bruteforce. Not so with smaller keyspaces).

So we have to run 2<sup>k</sup> outer decryptions, and *each of them* will require other 2<sup>k</sup> inner decryptions, making the total time 2<sup>k</sup> * 2<sup>k</sup>, or 2<sup>2k</sup>. In *this* scenario, 2-encryption with a k-key has the same strength of 1-encryption with a 2k-key.